# Изменение размера шрифта после загрузки шрифта

Tags: c++, imgui

Подскажите пожалуйста, в Imgui так и не появилось функции изменения рендера текста размером шрифта отличным от того, какой был сформирован при загрузки шрифта ?

Или же по прежнему, единственный вариант напечатать один и тот же текст разным размером одного и того же шрифта - это загрузить один и тот же шрифт дважды с необходимым указанным значением размера, и как итог заняв памяти минимум в два раза больше ?